# Using Chart.js in Wix (Velo) Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: chart.js, velo

I'm using this tutorial to draw charts using [chart.js in Wix Valo](https://www.wix.com/velo/example/chart.js-custom-element)

It works on some of the Wix pages

The code:

```
chart1 = new ChartJSAPI($w('#CustomElement1'))
chart1.customization = data_chart.customization
chart1.data = data_chart.data
```

But on some pages, I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at r.value (chart.js:8:33)
```

[image]

UPDATE:

The code look like:

```
chart1[index] = new ChartJSAPI($item('#customElement10'));
    chart1[index].customization = insight_cart_json.customization;
    chart1[index].data = insight_cart_json.data;
```

if I add this line for example or add a login bar I get the above error, if I remove this line, it works fine, why? and how to fix this:

```
$item("#insightImage").hide()
```

Suddenly, it sometimes works and sometimes gets an error

Comment: The code you're showing with error messages worked perfectly in the tutorial setting. What have you changed? Is `ChartElem` still in a `custom-elements` folder and declared as the source file for a custom element?

Comment: Yes, the file chart.js exists and contains `class ChartElem extends HTMLElement` and I made `import { ChartJSAPI } from 'public/chart-api';` I think nothing has change except that the page has more components and a large loading time, if I take the existing custom element and copy paste the code to a new page it works fine

Comment: It's very difficult to debug these things since there's no way to share the configuration in a sandbox - probably the issue is somewhere in the small details. You'll probably have to debug it yourself by console.log before the error happens, or using the velo debugger.

Comment: It looks like the custom element is trying to render before the necessary imports are completed

Comment: Update if I add $item("#insightImage").hide() for example, to the following code it shows the error without it working well, why? 
or if I add a profile image I get this error, why?